# How to make a grid reponsive?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, grid, dreamweaver

I have created a website and i am unable to make the tiled layout responsive. I am a beginner and i have no idea how to make my website responsive. Any help will be appreciated. The css and html is given below. Plus the background is repeating itself 3 times while i have added no repeat property in css.

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="tile hvr-reveal  " id="tile1">
    <div style="text-align: center;"> 
      <div class="img-with-text ">
        <p>
          <strong>
            <a href="Contact.html" style="text-decoration:none">Contact Us </a>
          </strong>
          <img src="homepage images/file242.png" alt="sometext" width="64" height="64" id="img0"/>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tile hvr-reveal"  id="tile2">
    <div style="text-align: center;"> 
      <div class="img-with-text">
        <p>
          <strong>
            <a href="products.html" style="text-decoration:none">Products</a>
          </strong>
          <img src="homepage images/shopping145.png" alt="sometext" width="64" height="64" id="img"/>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tile hvr-reveal " id="tile3">
    <div style="text-align: center;"> 
      <div class="img-with-text">
        <p>
          <strong>
            <a href="partners.html" style="text-decoration:none">Partners</a>
          </strong>
          <img src="homepage images/celebration19.png" alt="sometext" width="64" height="64" id="img2"/>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tile hvr-reveal" id="tile4">
    <div style="text-align: center;"> 
      <div class="img-with-text">
        <p>
          <strong>
            <a href="ABOUTUS.HTML" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a>
          </strong>
          <img src="homepage images/men16.png" alt="sometext" width="64" height="64" id="img1"/>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body { 
  font-family: chewy;   
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-image: url(pictures%20for%20web/bg3.jpg) ;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;

  **strong text**background-repeat: no-repeat;

  webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

.grid { 
  width: 1140px; 
  height: 650px; 
  margin: auto;
}


.tile {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  left: 451px;
  top: 152px;
  height: 152px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#tile1 {
  top: 407px;
  left: 754px;
  width: 338px;
  height: 196px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: #ff3300;
}

#tile2 {
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 980px;
  width: 148px;
  height: 154px;
  background-color: #008000;
}

#tile3 {
  top: 255px;
  left: 523px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #660066 ;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;    
}

#tile4 {
  top: 255px;
  left: 118px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #990000;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: You would find lots and lots of articles explaining how responsive design works. Just search for them and when you'd get stuck at some problem, we would be glad to help :)

Comment: If you're a beginner then use Bootstrap where the grid system is already built. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: A couple things that would help you - use percentages instead of px for widths.  This way your tiles scale appropriately when you resize your client.  Also, you should try to avoid `position: absolute;`.  This disrupts how your tiles respond to each other.  Like the above comment, tutorials for responsive design are easy to find and can get you started on the right foot

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background-color: #444;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.box:nth-of-type(1){
  background: yellow;
}
.box:nth-of-type(2){
  background: red;
}
.box:nth-of-type(3){
  background: blue;
}
.box:nth-of-type(4){
  background: green;
}
```

Which will keep the boxes aligned and depending on the width of the browser, shifts them.

http://codepen.io/DB1500/pen/JGqaBZ